# Stick a picture to the right side of the page.

Tags: css, image

I have a problem to stick a picture stick to the right side of the page.

Html code:

```
<img class="displayed" src="achtergrond.jpg" alt="achtergrond">
```

Css code:

```
 .displayed {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
margin-right:-8px;
margin-left:-8px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

I get the problem that the picture does not make contact with the right side of the page, but i set "margin-right: -8px"

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is the image inside a div or something? It would be helpful if you made a fiddle

Comment: Did you try `float: right;` ?

Comment: Kinda, when i try it it wil stick to the right side but it don't stick to the left side anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s4p3U/)

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    border-top: 2px solid red;
}
.myimage {
    border: 0px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 40px auto;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```